# Gzip for Phoenix's Plug.Conn.send_file

Tags: elixir, gzip, phoenix-framework

Is there a way to use send_file from Plug.Conn and to have it gzipped? I enabled :compress in config and it works fine for json responses but not for a send_file.

Answer (score 0):

As best I can tell, compressing the response body of `send_file/5` is not supported. Plug uses Cowboy under the hood, and its source code says in a comment, "[We do not compress sendfile bodies](https://github.com/ninenines/cowboy/blob/master/src/cowboy_compress_h.erl#L98)."

There's [a GitHub issue](https://github.com/ninenines/cowboy/issues/1237) that seems related, which discusses a possible workaround by swapping an uncompressed file with a compressed version, in case you are looking for options.